# Parallax Background Size

Tags: ios, parallax-scrolling

If I have three scrolling/continuous parallax backgrounds, what should be the ideal size (width/height) of the background images assuming I am going to support all devices including the new iPad?

**UPDATE:**

1. Only landscape mode
2. Deployment Target: 4.2+
3. Same scene will be repeated.

Comment: That really depends on the quality level you're shooting for and whether or not you want it to repeat any while on screen.

Comment: All the IOS mobile devices? Back to the first generation models too? Also, either the height or with width aren't as important depending on which way you're scrolling, so which way are you scrolling?

Comment: @Byte56 - I have updated the question section.

Comment: @Tetrad I updated the question portion. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new iPad has a resolution of `2048 x 1536`. That means in landscape mode (assuming you don't want to stretch the image) your background image would need to be 1536 pixels tall and at least 2048 pixels wide if you don't want a repeated portion in the same scene. Now you can either scale down for the other devices, or you can create additional art for the other devices. If you're scaling, just scale the height of the image and allow the scrolling feature to buffer any aspect ratio changes.

Comment: If I want double the size of the new iPad, what size should it be as the power of 2 applies? For landscape mode, does power of 2 also applies to height? Like if I've 256 in width, I have to have 256 also as height? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you want double the size of the new iPad, then you'd need the height to be at least (2048*2)=4096 by (1536*2)=3072. Power of two does not mean a square. It's frequently used with computers because  binary is the number system used in computer hardware.

Comment: It's a landscape parallax. Can't I just double the width and have the height the same, 4096 by 1536?

Comment: Yes, but you said double the size of the new iPad. You can make the width as large as you want, within memory and performance constraints.